# Should 'stopPropagation' prevent canvas from receiving mouse events on Fabricjs objects?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

This is a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find an answer.

I have a `fabricjs` canvas instance with a mouse eventListener attached. I also have a bunch of objects with mouse eventListeners. I do not want mouse events on the objects to get passed through to the canvas. `stopPropagation` and/or `stopImmediatePropagation` don't stop the events.

Am I using these methods wrong? Or is there a `Fabricjs` way to handle this?

---

Method on a class wrapping a `Fabricjs` canvas instance

```
this.canvas.on("mouse:down", this.handleMouseDown);
```

---

Method on a `Fabricjs` subclass:

```
testMouseDownHandler: function (event) {            
        event.e.stopPropagation();
        event.e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.e.preventDefault();
        if (event.e.shiftKey) {
            this.canvas.setActiveObject(this);
        }
    },
```

Comment: What order are the event listeners added? If they are both added to the canvas object then they will be executed in order of addition.

Comment: @traktor53 – the canvas has one event listener. The objects each have one event listener each. I don't see any order issue involved. The issue is that I don't want clicks on the objects to get passed through (bubble up) to the canvas.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Canvas elements can't have child elements, so nothing bubbles up to the canvas in DOM event handling. For fabric.js to handle widgets on the canvas, it must listen for mouse events on the canvas object.

Comment: Hey @NoGrabbing interesting issue, can you create a snippet reproducing the issue?

Comment: I tried event.e.stopPropagation(); and experienced success. So it worked for me in a mixed environment of Angular Components and a fabric Canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @traktor53 said in his comment there is no such thing as bubbling on a canvas object. In Konva.js they actually added their own event handling on object level where bubbling is simulated exactly like how you would expect in a normal DOM (more on that great feature of Konva in the docs for Konva.js here: https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Cancel_Propagation.html).

As far as I know it doesn't work like that for Fabric.js, but that doesn't mean you cannot prevent the execution of the event handler of the canvas when clicking on an object.

The main issue is that the canvas event fires before the object event meaning when you try to prevent "bubbling" inside the event handler of the object you are too late (in that sense it is indeed not "bubbling" towards the canvas).

I prevent the canvas event from executing simply by ignoring all canvas events that do have a target, it means it will only run when we clicked on nothing else but the canvas:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', (event) => {
    if(event.target !== null){
        //Ignore this event, we are clicking on an object (event.target is clicked object)
        return;
    }
    //... your canvas event handling code...
}

object.on('mousedown', (event) => {
    //... your object event handling code...
    let object = event.target;
}
```

Find all the other event names here in the docs: http://fabricjs.com/events

Hope this is helpful. If there are other (better solutions) please comment.

Comment: hey thanks. I get confused sometimes going back and forth between DOM, D3, Fabric/canvas.